I Got ERROR : Cannot query field \"queryName\" on type \"Query\".", Even if it is published in schema
In my project I am using ApolloStudio for publishing my graphql queries,
Using rover script I published my new query and it reflected in the changeLogs also in the API schema. But when I tried it on the explorer it is showing an error
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \"getApolloQuery\" on type \"Query\".",
      "extensions": {
        "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "GraphQLError: Cannot query field \"getApolloQuery\" on type \"Query\".",
            "    at Object.Field (/app/node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/FieldsOnCorrectTypeRule.js:48:31)",
            "    at Object.enter (/app/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:323:29)",
            "    at Object.enter (/app/node_modules/graphql/utilities/TypeInfo.js:370:25)",
            "    at visit (/app/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:243:26)",
            "    at Object.validate (/app/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:69:24)",
            "    at validate (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/requestPipeline.ts:452:12)",
            "    at Object.processGraphQLRequest (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/requestPipeline.ts:246:30)",
            "    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)",
            "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)",
            "    at processHTTPRequest (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/runHttpQuery.ts:331:24)"
          ]
        },
        "HttpStatusCode": 500
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

getApolloQuery is the new query I published. Every thing was working fine till last week, suddenly it happened like, the new queries and mutations are not accessible in the explorer. But it is getting reflected in the changelogs.
{
  "data": {
    "getApolloQuery": {
      "_id": "6641e71ec83611860bf04ace",
      "shipmentNumber": "TGLO-30062"
    }
  }
}

This is my expected response.

You believe the query is included in your schema but clearly it's not. Start by looking at your rover script which unfortunately you didn't include here.

npx -p @apollo/rover@latest rover graph introspect http://${SERVICE_NAME}/graphql | rover subgraph publish ${graphRef} --name ${SERVICE_NAME} --schema - --routing-url http://${SERVICE_NAME}/graphql --convert;
This is the script I am running to publish the schema in apollo graphql.
And the query is included in the schema.gql file. I have double checked it

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

when I am running the rover script which is in the above comment, The schema gets published in local server. But when trying to publish in the production server, the changes are getting reflected in the change logs section of apollo studio, But when trying to access any of the newly updated queries or mutations, an error is shown like given in the question.
If any additional details are required, please feel free to ask.
